# ListView with DataTemplate - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: c#, android-listview, xamarin, datatemplate, xamarin.forms

So I have this class:

```cs
public class MenuItem
{
    public string image { private set; get; }

    public string text { private set; get; }

    public MenuItem (string image, string text)
    {
        this.image = image;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

And the following ViewCell class:

```cs
public class MenuItemCell : ViewCell
{
    public MenuItemCell ()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            RowDefinitions = 
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Auto) },
            },
            ColumnDefinitions = 
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Auto) },
            }
        };

        var menuImage = new Image
        {
            IsVisible = true,
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
        };

        var text = new Label {
            TextColor = Color.Yellow,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
        };

        menuImage.SetBinding (ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "image");
        text.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "text");

        grid.Children.Add (menuImage, 0, 1, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add (text, 1, 2, 0, 1);

        this.View = grid;
    }
```

The content page is this:

```cs
public class Navigation : ContentPage
{
    ListView menu;
    ProfileView profile;
    DataTemplate viewTemplate;
    List<MenuItem> items;

    public Navigation ()
    {
        profile = new ProfileView ();

        items = new List<MenuItem> {
            new MenuItem ("menuTradeIconBig.png", "TRADE"),
            new MenuItem ("menuProfileIconBig.png", "PROFILE"),
            new MenuItem ("menuPositionsIconBig.png", "POSITIONS"),
        };

        menu = new ListView { RowHeight = 40 };
        menu.Header = profile;
        var viewTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(MenuItemCell));
        menu.ItemTemplate = viewTemplate;
        menu.ItemsSource = items;

        Content = new StackLayout { 
            Children = {    
                menu
            }
        };
    }
```

The problem is that when I click the button that is responsible for opening the content page, I get a

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

If I comment the `menu.ItemTemplate = viewTemplate;`, the page loads, but in the list view all items have the text `MyProjectName.MenuItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 year later, I got back to this question and found the problem in 5 seconds:

This line

```
menuImage.SetBinding (ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "image");
```

Should be like this

```
menuImage.SetBinding (Image.ImageSourceProperty, "image");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not provide the source for `ProfileView` or a more complete exception trace, one can only guess, but from the naming of it, it looks like you are setting a `View` to `menu.Header`, while it should instead be a view model, like `MenuItem` as you do not specify a `HeaderTemplate` for it.

So, first, I'd try

```cs
menu.Header = new MenuItem ("foo.png", "HEADER");
```

That probably won't give the visual you expect, but it shouldn't crash anymore. You an then configure the visual for the header with `HeaderTemplate`, an assign `menu.Header` to an object (yet to be defined) of type, e.g. `HeaderItem`

You'll get more info on the subject there http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#headerfooter

In any case, it might be worth reporting the issue to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Even if your code is incorrect due to a wrong model for the template, it shouldn't crash,

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still crashes with the same error. I even removed the header entirely just for testing, and it still crashes. I will look into the HeaderTemplate, but the issue isn't there.

Comment: please share a more complete trace

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking is because your attempting attempting to stuff a GridView into a ListView item Cell. I don't think thats going to have the outcome you where looking for. What you can do instead is create a stackLayout in your MenuItemCell and sets its orientation to Horizontal and you can still achieve the same desired effect.

Also when you get these messages an exception is usually thrown but it doesn't show up in that pop-up box that you talking about. So you need to view the application output to see exactly what happened.

In my opinion I would wrap the entire navigation code inside a try/catch block and on exception use the Debug.WriteLine() method to output the message and the stack trace so that way you can get a better handle on the error.

If there is no error thrown in navigation then its safe to assume the culprit is in the MenuItemCell Class which you can repeat the same process above.

I hope this helps.